# Can you set files as hidden in S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a possibility to set a file as a hidden file in an S3 Bucket like it works on a windows or mac machine (with a '.' prefix)? I don't mean to restrict access to this file by setting specific permissions for a user but just to have a file to be hidden which you wouldn't normally see if you browse the bucket with 'default' settings.

Comment: If you set bucket in versioned mode, and delete the object, it will be not visible by default.

Comment: No, not really though Marcin's idea could be helpful. You might consider having a second, shadow bucket that you move objects to/from in order to hide/unhide them.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to hide some objects? Can you tell us more about your use-case.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible to filter files returned for a List operation. On the other hand, you can limit which *folders* the user can list, so you can make files hidden in such directories.

Here are some link how to configure it:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/